# Time series dynamic poisson regression

Tags: regression, time-series, poisson-distribution, count-data, dynamic-regression

I have a time series count data by customers that I would like to regress on past months items (count) sold and promotional effects (current and past). Below is an example, and the dataset has one record per customer.

Y= number of items (count) sold

**Customer 1:** 
Y/Count data (current month) = Y/count data(past month) + promo data (current month) + promo data (past month)

**Customer 2:** 
Y/Count data (current month) = Y/count data(past month) + promo data (current month) + promo data (past month)

I'm not sure what is the right model to use. I could use Dynamic regression/ARIMAX if my response was a continous variable. But the response variable in my hand is a count data, so I'm not sure if ARIMAX is the right model for this problem.
In addition, I have lot of zeros in my response variable (similar to zero inflated poisson regression).

I did search in standard textbooks and the internet, I did not come across any regrssion model with time series count data. I would really appreciate if anyone could recommend an appropriate model  for this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at Trivedi's notes on [Poisson model with exponential feedback (sec. 23)](http://www.stata.com/meeting/mexico10/mex10sug_trivedi.pdf) and the Windmeijer paper he cites. They may be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a zero-inflated Poisson or negative binomial dynamic model would be adequate. If you are using R, you might want to look at package [ZIM](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ZIM/index.html).